# Return undefined when query to model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to access the content of array of document in my model, but I can't and return undefined.  
here is my model(Project.js):

```
var mongoose = require('moongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require("./Users");

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   description: String,
   owner: {
   type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
   },
   contributor: [{
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
   }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

and my Api:

```
var Project = require('./Project')

await Project.find({owner: userId, name: name})
.then(project => {

   console.log(project);
   console.log(project.contributor);
}).catch(err => {
   res.status(500).send({
   message: err.message
   });
});
```

when i try **console.log(project);** return expected output but in **console.log(project.contributor);** return **undefined**

I've also searched the web but couldn't find anything right and clear solution

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Please show output of console.log(project)

Comment: project.contributor is an array with one object, so you need to determent witch one you want even though there is only one object in the array, so try console.log(project.contributor[0])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `project` is an array, not an object. Thus you have to use `project[0].contributor`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are expecting to find only one project, change find by findOne method. Other case you are searching for several projects and you are going to receive an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Your output from `Project.find()` ([See](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)) will be an array of objects from the database.

If you will only have 1 object as a result then you can use `project[0].contributor` because `project` is an array with 1 object inside it, which is on the index 0.

If the result might have many objects in the array then you should iterate through the result to get each of the data individually.

```
project.forEach(p => console.log(p.contributor))
```